# CakePHP searching multiple models

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, conditional-statements, cakephp-3.x

I have a table called **users** and it is connected to **coaches** and **clients**.

I want to search in both users table and coaches table.

My tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `team07`.`users` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `usertype` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `modified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `phonenumber` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `suburb` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `businessname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` BLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

And also

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `team07`.`coaches` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `coachid` INT NOT NULL,
  `appstate` INT NOT NULL,
  `bio` VARCHAR(2048) NULL,
  `price` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `COACH_INFOFK_idx` (`coachid` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `coachid_UNIQUE` (`coachid` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `COACH_INFOFK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`coachid`)
    REFERENCES `team07`.`users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is what the code I am doing looks like:

```
  public function review()
    {
      //Select all users which are a Coach AND have appstate = 1 (Just signed up, in review)     
      $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);
      $users = $this->Users->find('all')->where(['Users.usertype'=>'CO', 'Coaches.appstate'=>'1']);

      $this->set(compact('users'));
      $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
    }
```

However I am having issues because my page responds with

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'Coaches.appstate' in 'where clause'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the association is understood by cake, you can use contain to load it:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations

So something like this:

```
public function review()
{
    //Select all users which are a Coach AND have appstate = 1 (Just signed up, in review)     
    $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);
    $users = $this->Users->find('all')->contain(['Coaches'])->where(['Users.usertype'=>'CO', 'Coaches.appstate'=>'1']);

    $this->set(compact('users'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I associate my tables? What do I write in my Model>Entity files?

Comment: If you used cake bake to generate the models based on the database tables, it could be that cake already detected the associations. I'm not sure though, since I think cake expects the coachid column in the coaches database to be called 'user_id'. Since the id is actually the id of a user, from the users table. For more info: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Comment: Great, thanks I just re did the database. In coaches do I need an id attribute as a PK or is user_id just fine? What is the proper way to do it for cake?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary for cake to understand the association, but having the id column of a table as a primary key is usually a good idea.

Comment: Thanks so much my friend. You have helped me a lot.